# How to ignore errors from PDFMiner in order to avoid Python script from breaking

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdfminer

I'm fairly new to file handling especially PDFs. I currently have PDFminer.six installed and have tested out several functions that extracts text from PDF files. I also have another function that takes in a list of PDF files and then calls the first PDF extraction function to extract all the text from each file.

The problem is that, I have a lot of PDF files and the script seems to break every time it encounters a new error. Its difficult to have go and search for which PDF file caused the error regardless of whether it was an unrecognized character, or different encoding, or encryption etc..

How can I make it so the script just continues to run regardless of the type of error? Could I set the PDF extraction function to ignore any type of error? Or perhaps, am I missing something in my code that would assist me with addressing this issue?

```py
p = Path("C:/Users/Hugo Caldeira/Desktop")
inp = r"((?<=|^)[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}(?=|$))"

file_dict = {
    "name" : [],
    "created" : [],
    "modified" : [],
    'path' : [],
    'content' : [],
    'keyword' : []
}

files = list(p.rglob('*pdf'))

def pdfparser(file):
    fp = open(file, 'rb')
    rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
    retstr = io.StringIO()
    codec = 'utf-8'
    laparams = LAParams()
    device = TextConverter(rsrcmgr, retstr, codec=codec,  laparams=laparams)
    #Create a PDF interpreter object.
    interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)
    #Process each page contained in the document.
    for page in PDFPage.get_pages(fp):
        interpreter.process_page(page)
        data =  retstr.getvalue()

    return(data)


def pdfs(files):
    for name in files:
            #print(name)
            IP_list = (pdfparser(name))
            #print(IP_list)
            keyword = re.findall(inp,IP_list)
            #print(ip_test)
            file_dict['keyword'].append(keyword)
            file_dict['name'].append(name.name[0:])
            file_dict['created'].append(time.ctime(name.stat().st_ctime))
            file_dict['modified'].append(time.ctime(name.stat().st_mtime))
            file_dict['path'].append(name)
            file_dict["content"].append(IP_list)
            #print(file_dict)
    return(file_dict)

pdfs(files)

def to_xlsx():
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(file_dict)
    df.head()
    df.to_excel("pdftest.xlsx")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    to_xlsx()
```

The current error I am getting is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Hugo Caldeira/Desktop/Scripts/pdf.py", line 67, in <module>
    print(pdfparser(p))
  File "c:/Users/Hugo Caldeira/Desktop/Scripts/pdf.py", line 32, in pdfparser
    fp = open(file, 'rb')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Hugo Caldeira\\Desktop\\test_folder\\Desktop'

(base) C:\Users\Hugo Caldeira\Desktop\Scripts>"C:/Users/Hugo Caldeira/Anaconda3/python.exe" "c:/Users/Hugo Caldeira/Desktop/Scripts/pdf.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Hugo Caldeira/Desktop/Scripts/pdf.py", line 64, in <module>
    pdfs(files)
  File "c:/Users/Hugo Caldeira/Desktop/Scripts/pdf.py", line 52, in pdfs
    IP_list = (pdfparser(name))
  File "c:/Users/Hugo Caldeira/Desktop/Scripts/pdf.py", line 42, in pdfparser
    for page in PDFPage.get_pages(fp):
  File "C:\Users\Hugo Caldeira\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pdfminer\pdfpage.py", line 129, in get_pages
    doc = PDFDocument(parser, password=password, caching=caching)
  File "C:\Users\Hugo Caldeira\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pdfminer\pdfdocument.py", line 577, in __init__
    self._initialize_password(password)
  File "C:\Users\Hugo Caldeira\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pdfminer\pdfdocument.py", line 603, in _initialize_password
    handler = factory(docid, param, password)
  File "C:\Users\Hugo Caldeira\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pdfminer\pdfdocument.py", line 303, in __init__
    self.init()
  File "C:\Users\Hugo Caldeira\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pdfminer\pdfdocument.py", line 310, in init
    self.init_key()
  File "C:\Users\Hugo Caldeira\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pdfminer\pdfdocument.py", line 325, in init_key
    raise PDFPasswordIncorrect
pdfminer.pdfdocument.PDFPasswordIncorrect
```

The other errors I encountered before were:

```
PDFSyntaxError: No /Root object! - Is this really a PDF?
```

Comment: Sorry about the format. Had some trouble getting it formatted

Comment: Look in a Python tutorial for how to write a `try...except` block.

Answer (score 0):

Use try and except.

https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions

In your except clause make sure you output the filename and the exception.

Comment: Thank you. And sorry I'm a little new to except clauses, would I create an except clauses and put it in the pdfparser function or the PDF function?

Comment: Either could work OK.  Perhaps the simplest is to put `IP_list = (pdfparser(name))` in the try block.  Though I now notice you are also getting `FileNotFoundError`.  That's a separate problem.